# AWSWrangler chucksize with data type conversion and conversion to Parquet

Tags: python, aws, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that reads in json files and then converts to parquet from S3. I came across an issue where if the files are greater than 1GB, lambda runs out of memory. I'm using awswrangler to read in the json and writing to parquet and after doing some research found chunksize to read the files in chunk. The issue is since I'm reading it in chunks, I have to convert the parquets in chunks which creates multiple parquet files. I only want one parquet file. I couldn't find something where I can do that. Any help is appreciated.

```
nRows = 0
for dfChunk in wr.s3.read_json(path=[s3_json_location], lines=True, orient='records', chunksize=1000)
   nRows = nRows + len(dfChunk)
   print("processed {0}".format(nRows))
   dfChunk = dfChunk.astype(str)
   wr.s3.to_parquet(df=dfChunk, path=Path, dataset=True, mode='append', compression=None)
```